# R making space for the xaxis labels

Tags: r, plot, label

I have the following boxplots
[image]

as you can see my problem is that the lables are not fitting in my figure since they are exceeding the margins of the figure, I tried to use the **par** function and its **mars** attribute that shows the margins, but didn't work for me, I used par(par()$mar+c(10,0,0,0))

If you got any idea for my problem please let me know

Answer (score 4):

You don't appear to have assigned your newly created `mar` parameter to the `mar` parameter

Compare

```
d <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=1:5)
boxplot(d)

# your call was
# par(par()$mar+c(10,0,0,0)) which doesn't specify which 
# par is being set (and returns NULL, (A vague hint that it isn't working properly)
par(mar = par('mar') + c(10,0,0,0))
boxplot(d)
```

Comment: `par("mar")` is most often used, not `par()$mar`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson - very true, fixed my laziness.